# RealmSwift: How to create To-One Relationships properly?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Let's assume I have:

```
class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var race = ""
    dynamic var name = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "race"
    }
}

class Person: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var address = ""
    dynamic var dog: Dog?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "name"
    }
}
```

First I create a `Dog` and save it:

```
let dog = Dog()
dog.race = "Dalmatian"

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(dog, update: true)
}
```

Now I create a `Person` in a different class. The docs are quite a bit unclear about this scenario. Do I need to save changes for the `Dog` first before creating the relationship?:

```
let person = Person()
person.name = "Jim"

// retrieve dog from realm: 

if let dog = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(Dog.self, key: "Dalmatian") {
    dog.name = "Rex" // Owner gives dog a new name

    // Question:
    // Saving changes to Rex: is this step neccessary?
    try! realm.write {
         realm.add(dog, update: true)
    }

    person.dog = dog
}

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(person, update: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and it will cause a crash

```
if let dog = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(Dog.self, key: "Dalmatian") {
    dog.name = "Rex" // Owner gives dog a new name

    person.dog = dog
}
```

if you want update the `dog`'s `name`, write like this:

```
if let dog = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(Dog.self, key: "Dalmatian") {

        try! realm.write({ 
            dog.name = "Rex"
        })

        person.dog = dog

    }
```

see more: [Realm.io/updating-objects](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#updating-objects)

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a whole object graph as unmanaged objects and persist them all by one call. So you don't need to persist the Dog first and retrieve it again to be able to use it in a relationship.

```
let dog = Dog()
dog.race = "Dalmatian"

let person = Person()
person.name = "Jim"
person.dog = dog

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(person, update: true)
}
```

Comment: Bht sometimes this is neccessary, because I create them in different classes.